# python polars: way to pass partition iterator to threadpool?

Tags: python-polars

I have a situation where I use `partition_by` in a for loop, which then calls a function which transforms the partition dataframe into a new dataframe.

```py
partition_obj = df.partition_by(partition_by)
for partition_by_df in partition_obj:
    new_df = self._process_partition(partition_by_df)
```

Is it possible to pass `partition_obj` to a pool thread? Something along the lines of:

```py
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

partition_obj = df.partition_by(partition_by)
for results_df in pool.imap_unordered(self._process_partition, partition_obj):
   # Concat all of the resulting dataframes
```

thx

Comment: You'd use a process pool: https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/misc/multiprocessing/  (Assuming there's no way to implement `_process_partition` in Polars natively.)

Comment: This seems like it might be an XY problem. If you're trying to force parallelization, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76672449/polars-speedup-by-using-partition-by-and-collect-all/76681132#76681132)

Comment: Does `self._process_partition` hold the GIL? If so there may be no speed benefit to running it in a thread pool.