Using multiprocessing to apply a function on a dictionary containing polars dataframes
I am currently trying to modify a large polars dataframe by applying a function across the entire dataframe. This is necessary as I need to divide the dataframe into intervals based on time, for each unique value of an id column. I have made a dictionary where each key is a unique value of x leading to an item which is a polars dataframe where the id column only has the key value. I have then tried to apply multiprocessing to use all my available cores to iterate through the dictionary and apply my function to each of them. This does not give the desired result as my code runs for unreasonably long and eats all my RAM. I suspect my implementation of a multiprocessing solution is the reason.
I have done the following:
Used an added index column in the dataframe as well as other column values to write a series of conditions that should trigger a new interval. Then tried to divide the dictionary and pass it to the multiprocessing.
Here is the code from the multiprocessing:
cores = mp.cpu_count()

def process_identifier(i):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return os.getpid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     with mp.Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
        # Use chunksize to balance load
        process_identifier_list = pool.map(process_identifier, range(cores))

        process_identifier_dict = {id: idx for idx, id in enumerate(process_identifier_list)}

        task_list = [(process_identifier_dict, value) for key,value in df_dict.items()]

        print("Simulation started")


        results = list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(func_interval_divider, task_list), total=len(task_list)))

        
df_new = pl.concat(results)

Edited to include my function:
def func_interval_divider(df):

print(df.columns)
print(df)

interval_counter = 0
interval_length = 480

patient_index_list = df.get_column('patient_index').to_numpy()

for i in patient_index_list:
    #start of the data
    if i == 0: 
        df = df.with_columns(INTERVAL_ID = pl.when(
            pl.col('patient_index').is_between(0, interval_length))
                .then(pl.lit(interval_counter))
                .otherwise(pl.col('INTERVAL_ID')
                    )
                )
        interval_counter += 1
    #rest of the data
    if (i+interval_length >= np.max(patient_index_list) and df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==i).select(pl.col("INTERVAL_ID")).item() == 0) or (i % interval_length ==0 and i!=0):
        interval_counter += 1
        
        df = df.with_columns(INTERVAL_ID = pl.when(
            pl.col('patient_index').is_between(i, i + interval_length))
                .then(pl.lit(interval_counter))
                .otherwise(pl.col('INTERVAL_ID')
                   )
                )

    else:
        pass

    
for i in patient_index_list:
    #SAE interval_id
    if df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==i).select(pl.col("SAE_INTERVAL")).item() == 1 and df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==int(i-1)).select(pl.col("SAE_INTERVAL")).item() == 0:
        interval_counter += 1
        df = df.with_columns(INTERVAL_ID = pl.when(
            pl.col('patient_index').is_between(i, i + interval_length),
            pl.col('SAE_INTERVAL') == 1)
                .then(pl.lit(interval_counter))
                .otherwise(pl.col('INTERVAL_ID')
                    )
                )
    # edge case where two SAE_intervals follow each other 
    if df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==i).select(pl.col("SAE_INTERVAL")).item() == 1 and df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==i+1).select(pl.col("SAE_INTERVAL")).item() == 1 and df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==i).select(pl.col("INTERVAL_ID")).item()> df.filter(pl.col('patient_index')==i+1).select(pl.col("INTERVAL_ID")).item():
        interval_counter += 1
        df = df.with_columns(INTERVAL_ID = pl.when(
            pl.col('patient_index').is_between(i, i + interval_length),
            pl.col('SAE_INTERVAL') == 1)
                .then(pl.lit(interval_counter))
                .otherwise(pl.col('INTERVAL_ID')
                    )
        )
    
    else:
        pass


return df

Edit x2:
The interval ID rules are as follows:
Every x index the interval_id should += 1 and set the next x rows to have that new interval value as their value in the INTERVAL_ID column.
The interval value should reset such that it restarts form 0 when encountering a new value in the PATIENT_ID column. I have also considered a global interval_id instead but it seemed to have many more edge cases.
A new interval value should be forced as soon as a row has 1 in the SAE column, and set the next x rows to have that updated interval id value, but immediately stopping if SAE is no longer 1.
If there are more than x SAE ==1 in a row, the interval_id should increase by one after x rows of SAE ==1, and then set the succeeding SAE == 1 to have that new interval value either stopping when encountering a 0 or repeating that process if this new interval is longer than x.

If you use LazyFrames, Polars can do its own parallelism with .collect_all() - similar to what is described in https://stackoverflow.com/q/76672449

I am unsure from the example on how to apply my own custom function to all elements of partition_by, could you elaborate?

What does the custom function do? Can you show it?

Edit: added my custom function

Thanks for the update. I think the real question here is how can one perform the task "natively" using Polars. The current approach of looping over .get_column().to_numpy() is just extremely innefficient. A "proper" solution would mean there would be no need to try use multiprocessing to speed it up. If you can explain the actual interval_id rules with a before/after example then people could provide native solutions.

thank you for your answer, I am aware that my current solution is likely very inefficient and doesnt utilize polars to its full potential, that fact that I recently switched from pandas to polars is likely why.
I have updated the post to contain the interval rules

You'll also need to provide a before/after dataframe. (i.e. a minimal reproducible example) - It may be simpler to just create a new question at this stage without any mention of the multiprocessing stuff.

Have you tried building a user-defined function which you then invoke with map_groups() which is similar to apply()?

No I havent actually tried that, I can give it a try and say how it goes
